# React does not recognize the X prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I am beginner developer and I am working on react (gatsby, TS, styled components) project. I am getting this error:

"React does not recognize the `isOpen` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `isopen` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element."

```
export const Navigation = () => {
      const [isNavigationOpen, setIsNavigationOpen] = useState(false);
      const { isTablet } = useQuery();
    
      const showNavbar = () => {
        setIsNavigationOpen((previousState) => !previousState);
      };
    
      const renderElement = isTablet ? (
        <>
          <SvgStyled
            src='bars_icon'
            isOpen={isNavigationOpen}
            onClick={showNavbar}
          />
          <MobileNavigation isOpen={isNavigationOpen}>
            {NAVIGATION_DATA.map(({ id, url, text }) => (
              <LinkMobile key={id} to={url}>
                <ExtraSmallParagraph>{text}</ExtraSmallParagraph>
              </LinkMobile>
            ))}
          </MobileNavigation>
        </>
      ) : (
        <FlexWrapper>
          {NAVIGATION_DATA.map(({ id, url, text }) => (
            <LinkDekstop key={id} to={url}>
              <ExtraSmallParagraph>{text}</ExtraSmallParagraph>
            </LinkDekstop>
          ))}
        </FlexWrapper>
      );
    
      return renderElement;
    };
```

I am sure that I am missing some fundamental react stuff or something. Maybe someone could help me and explain the reason of this error.

Comment: Can you share the `SvgStyled` component code in your question?

Comment: const SvgStyled = styled(Svg)<{ isOpen: boolean }>`
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  ${({ isOpen }) => isOpen && `transform: rotate(90deg);`};

  &:hover {
    ${({ isOpen }) =>
      isOpen
        ? `transform: rotate(90deg);`
        : `transform: scale(0.98);`};
  }
`;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When this happens it is because all props passed to the styled component are then also passed down to the DOM element that you are styling.

You've likely a component that looks like the following:

```
const SvgStyled = styled(SVG)<{ isOpen: boolean }>`
  // your CSS and logic referencing the `isOpen` prop
`;
```

To resolve this issue you refactor the styled component definition and explicitly pass only the props you want to the element being styled. Use an anonymous function component and destructure the prop you don't want to pass on to the DOM element, and spread the rest of the props. This ensures the `className` prop that `styled-components` is creating a CSS class for is passed through.

Example:

```
interface SvgStyledProps {
  className?: string,
  isOpen: boolean,
}

const SvgStyled = styled(({ isOpen, ...props}) => (
  <Svg {...props} />
))<SvgStyledProps>`
  // your CSS and logic referencing the `isOpen` prop
`;
```

For any other Typescript specifics/caveats with `styled-components` see [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript).

Answer (score 11):

As of styled components `v5.1`, you can alternatively prevent undesired props from being passed down to your React node by prefixing it with a dollar sign (`$`) and designating it as a `transient prop`:

```
const SvgStyled = styled(SVG)<{ $isOpen: boolean }>`
  // your CSS and logic referencing the `$isOpen` prop
`;
// SVG does NOT receive props.$isOpen
```

[docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props)

Comment: Great answer. I think this is the way to go since v5.1

Comment: nice, transient props!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `shouldForwardProp` as [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop) recommended:

```
    const SvgStyled = styled(SVG).withConfig({
         shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'isOpen',
    })<{ isOpen: boolean }>`
    `;
```

Answer (score 0):

use $ like this :

```js
const SvgStyled = styled(SVG)<{ $isOpen: boolean }>`
  // your CSS stuff
`;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).